# Vim syntax for getting name of current file

Tags: bash, vim

In Vim, I can echo the current filename using this command:

```
:echo @%
```

I found that information here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file

Can someone explain why the `@` symbol is necessary? If I enter the command without the `@` symbol, I get an error:

```
E15: Invalid expression: %
E15: Invalid expression: %
```

However, if I try to send the filename to a `bang` command as an argument, including the `@` sign appears as a regular character in the argument. Removing the `@` sign works.  In other words, in my `.bash_profile` I have the following function:

```
test_func() {
        echo $1
}
```

In Vim, I run:

```
:! test_func @%    #outputs @path/to/my/file
:! test_func %     #outputs path/to/my/file
```

What is the `@` symbol doing and why does it behave differently when sending the output to a bash function?

Comment: I presume you know `Ctrl+G` but want something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is `:h expr-register`:

> register                      *expr-register* *@r*
>
> ---
>
> @r            contents of register 'r'
>
> The result is the contents of the named register, as a single string.
>   Newlines are inserted where required.  To get the contents of the unnamed
>   register use @" or @@.  See |registers| for an explanation of the available
>   registers.
>
> When using the '=' register you get the expression itself, not what it
>   evaluates to.  Use |eval()| to evaluate it.

As to why you don't need that for `:!` that is probably because of `:h cmdline-special`.

> 6. Ex special characters              *cmdline-special*
>
> Note: These are special characters in the executed command line.  If you want
>   to insert special things while typing you can use the CTRL-R command.  For
>   example, "%" stands for the current file name, while CTRL-R % inserts the
>   current file name right away.  See |c_CTRL-R|.
>
> Note: If you want to avoid the special characters in a Vim script you may want
>   to use |fnameescape()|.
>
> In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be used, the following
>   characters have a special meaning.  These can also be used in the expression
>   function expand() |expand()|.
>     %   Is replaced with the current file name.       *:_%* *c_%*

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain this in a simpler way? I don't know what `:h expr-register` and `:h cmdline-special` mean.

Comment: Those are vim help commands. Run them in vim to see the help items.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the `@` symbol is doing. Is it shorthand for something?

Comment: You might as well ask "What is `:`? Is it short for something?" I think. It just *is*. `@` is the indicator/sigil, in eval contexts, for a register. The way `$` is the sigil for variables in the shell. It is the difference between `:echo %` (where `%` is an invalid expression)  and `:echo "%"` (where `"%"` is a string) and `:echo @%` (where `@%` is an eval expression for the `%` register).

Comment: The difference between `:! test_func @%` and `:! test_func %` is interesting, `%` is not the same in both cases.  In the former case `%` is a register and `@%` is evaluated as an expression, in the latter `%` is a `cmdline-special`.  The result just happens to be the same.

Comment: @lcd047 I don't believe that is true. Look at the output from that test. In the `@%` case the `@` makes it into the shell function argument. I believe the `%` is `cmdline-special` in both and `@` is just treated as a string "prefix".

Comment: @Etan Reisner Hmm, right, `@` is just passed along.

Comment: When using %, very useful modifiers are available:  %:t gives the file name without path, %:p gives a full path even if the file was opened without a path specified, %:h gives the path the file was opened with (or . if no path was specified), %:r is the file name without dot extension, and %:e is the dot extension.

Answer (score 10):

**`:echo` takes a Vimscript *expression*, whereas `:!` takes and *external command*, which is a special case for a *filename*, which is accepted by `:edit` et al.**

For external commands and filenames, there are special characters such as `%` and `#`, described under `:help cmdline-special`. This also includes this crucial sentence:

> In Ex commands, **at places where a file name can be used**, the following
>   characters have a special meaning.

In contrast, `:echo` does not take a filename, but an expression. There are several ways to resolve the current filename; the most direct is via `expand()`:

```
:echo expand('%')
```

Alternatively, as the current filename is also stored in a special register `%`, and registers are addressed via the `@` sigil:

```
:echo @%
```

#### The other way around

This also explains the frequent question of why `:edit g:variable` doesn't work as expected. Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate a variable (or expression); otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the variable name itself as the argument.